# Friendship Data Model In Parse Android

Tags: android, parse-platform

Hi I am working on a social networking app, where i want to have a functionality of adding friends.

I am using parse database for doing so.

I guess there are two options  for
1. Using relation 
2. Using Pointers.

Which will be better and why ? I should be writing this code in cloud or client side ?

Comment: Well since it is rare that people have more than hundreds of friends I guess pointer array would do. Relation would however be the safer choice. How you implement it depends on your needs, supporting multiple platforms etc.

Comment: @cYrixmorten do you have some example for friendship model ?

Comment: Unfortunately no, but I suspect that join tables might be a viable solution